# Gearing for Multiple Forward / Reverse on Single Drive Shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, gears

This model illustrates my question:

- Red is a motor
- Green is the drive shaft
- Orange are nylon straps
- Blue are spools for the straps

I want to be able to drive multiple spools in multiple directions at the same time. They should be individually controllable and able to stay still, wind, or unwind. They may all move at the same speed.

My best guess is that this has something to do with idler gears, planetary gears, and servo-controlled clutches. But I don't really understand how to employ these, or know whether I'm on the right track.

I appreciate any help! I'm especially interested in solutions which are cost effective and robust.

This seems common enough that there must be a solution already?

[image]

Comment: Without reversing, see "fast and loose" pulleys from old shaft drives. Perhaps a third pulley per belt with an epicyclic built in to reverse it?

Comment: Is it not feasible to just independently drive each of the pulleys with a smaller motor? 

I can't see a very cheap, simple or reliable system (definitely not one that is cost efficient or robust) coming about by having such control from only one motor. 

If packaging is a problem maybe have 1 large pump and then several hydraulic motors?